# Parent - child structure from multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to assigning values of two nested dictionaries to each other. For example, if we assume parent and child and then the grandchild how would be assigned to the corresponding child. (Parent is the key and value is the child and then child is the key and value is grandchild)

I'm trying to import large datasets from a sqlite database and then based on the parent and child relationships that I need, are grouped into dictionaries accordingly. This is to create a dictionary of nested dictionaries to populate a qmenu, where the inputs must stay in dictionary format. I'm not familiar with how to make it more efficient as through mapping or recursive.

My current code **works** the way I want it to, but is there any way to make it more efficient or recursive?

```
# DATA
A = ['item0','item1']
B = [['item00','item01','item02'],['item11','item12']]
C = [['item000'],['item010','item011'],['item020'],['item110','item111'],['item120']]


# FLATTEN B
B_ls = []
for i in range(len(C)):
    B_ls = [item for sublist in B for item in sublist]

# INITAIATE DICTIONARIES
master = {}
parent = {}
child = {}

# INITIATE CELL CONTENT COUNTER
skipper = 0

# CREATE NESTED DICITIONARIES
for j in range(len(A)):
    child = {}
    for i in range(len(B)):
        tempD1 = {B_ls[i+skipper]:C[i+skipper]}
        child.update(tempD1)
    parent = {A[j]:child}
    master.update(parent)
    skipper += len(B[j])

# CHECK RESULTS
print(master)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach using a nested dictionary comprehension -

The idea is to build the parent-child structure by `zipping` both `A` and `B` in the outer loop, given that there are as many parent `keys` as sublists or childs in `B`.

Now, each of these childs are supposed to contain as `value` the sublists contained in `C`, so we can create an [`iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and retrieve its `next` item each time we want to set a new grandchild in the inner dictionary comprehension:

```
A = ['item0','item1']
B = [['item00','item01','item02'],['item11','item12']]
C = iter([['item000'],['item010','item011'],['item020'],['item110','item111'],['item120']])
```

---

```
d = {p:{gs:next(C) for gs in s} for p,s in zip(A,B)}

{'item0': {'item00': ['item000'],
           'item01': ['item010', 'item011'],
           'item02': ['item020']},
 'item1': {'item11': ['item110', 'item111'], 
           'item12': ['item120']}}
```

Comment: Thank you! Looking at your method even made me find a bug in my version. You rock!